# Press key to perform action when ScrollLock is on AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make a script that when press `x` to cut, `c` to copy and `v` to paste if the ScrollLock is on.

Here is my script that is not working, it will perform cut, copy and paste no matter ScrollLock is on or off.

```
~ScrollLock::
KeyWait, ScrollLock
GetKeyState, ScrollLockState, ScrollLock, T
If ScrollLockState = D
{
    x:: Send, ^x
    c:: Send, ^c
    v:: Send, ^v
}
```

And for the script below, I cannot type `x`, `c` and `v` when ScrollLock is off, but can cut, copy and paste when ScrollLock is on.

```
~ScrollLock::
KeyWait, ScrollLock
GetKeyState, ScrollLockState, ScrollLock, T

x::
If ScrollLockState = D
{
Send, ^x
return
}

c::
If ScrollLockState = D
{
Send, ^c
return
}

v::
If ScrollLockState = D
{
Send, ^v
return
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in the following way:

```
#If GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T")
x::Send, ^x
c::Send, ^c
v::Send, ^v
#If
```